# How to calculate the outgoing call ( which I dialed from my app) duration in android programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call, android-phone-call

I have given the permission in `manifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

**And define a receiver:**

```
<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**The receiver file is:**

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String TAG = "AUTODIAL";
static long start_time, end_time, call_duration;
String number;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "intent get data : "+intent.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Phone State : "+state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(state==null) {
        number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Out going Phone number : "+number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        call_duration = end_time - start_time;
}
}
```

Here, it is giving all out going call duration and not only the ones I dialed from my app .

And is it possible to go back to my app after dialing from it?

Comment: This might help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493360/get-last-call-duration-in-android

Comment: here getContentResolver is used but as i am dialing from app through  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_number)); callIntent.putExtra("flag",1);
    context.startActivity(callIntent);
 So I need to calculate inside onReceive()

Answer (score 2):

below is a code of detecting outgoing call by accessibility events -

Add a class which extends `AccessibilityService` in your projects -

```
public class CallDetection extends AccessibilityService {
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
     acquireLock(this);
    Log.d("myaccess","after lock");
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED) {
        Log.d("myaccess","in window changed");
        AccessibilityNodeInfo info = event.getSource();
        if (info != null && info.getText() != null) {
            String duration = info.getText().toString();
            String zeroSeconds = String.format("%02d:%02d", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0)});
            String firstSecond = String.format("%02d:%02d", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(1)});
            Log.d("myaccess","after calculation - "+ zeroSeconds + " --- "+ firstSecond + " --- " + duration);
            if (zeroSeconds.equals(duration) || firstSecond.equals(duration)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Call answered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // Your Code goes here
            }
            info.recycle();
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    info.notificationTimeout = 0;
    info.packageNames = null;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {

}
}
```

But to get the function `event.getSource()` working you have to specify some of your service configuration through xml, so create a **xml** folder in your project and add a xml file called  **serviceconfig.xml** (you can give any name you want.

The content of serviceconfig is below -

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/callDetection"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
/>
```

You can find more about **serviceconfig** in [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html)

Now add your service in you **Manifest** file like this -

```
<service android:name=".CallDetection"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        android:label="@string/callDetection">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig" />
</service>
```

And youre done, just run the app and go to **Accessibility settings** in your phone, you will find an option named as **detection** (*or whatever name you have given as your service description*), switch that on to give accesibility permissions for you app.

Now you will see a toast when call is answered.

you can Code any code you want in there, also you can call a callback function in your activity

**Most important** - Dont call your call window(android dialer window) untill the call is answered, otherwise this will not work.

**Note** - As android doesn't provide any solution to detect if the call is answered or not, this is the best alternative i have made, hope it works for you.